# create a sequence of numbers written in letters

Tags: r

How can I create a sequence of numbers but those numbers should be written in letters, i.e. "one" instead of 1 / "two" instead of 2. I want to create a vector of numbers from 100 to 1 (in reverse order) and the numbers need to be written in letters.
TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `english` package for this.

```
library(english)

as.english(100:1)

[1] one hundred   ninety nine   ninety eight  ninety seven  ...
```

Or for character output:

```
words(100:1) 

[1] "one hundred"   "ninety nine"   "ninety eight"  "ninety seven" ...
```

Edit:  As neilfws notes `words()` will produce character strings which might be more useful if you want to continue to process the data.  `as.english()` is a print/format method.

Comment: I knew there must be a package! FYI if you want the class of the output to be character instead of "english", you can use `words(1:10)`.

Answer (score 2):

Copy and paste [this R function](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/psychemedia/150cb9901529da58124a/raw/a12bfd600af11065255f39787c965b7a4be086d0/numbers2words.R).

Then run:

```
numbers2words(100:1)
```

Testing using 10 to 1 (100 to 1 works, but I didn't want to paste the large output here):

```
numbers2words(10:1)

 [1] "ten"   "nine"  "eight" "seven" "six"   "five"  "four"  "three" "two"   "one"
```

EDIT: better still use `english::words(100:1)` as in the answer from H 1.